# How to setup Angular 2 project with local dev and remote deployment

Tags: angular, typescript, phpstorm, node-modules

I have a large Angular 2 project which is connected to a git repository. Develop environment is my local machine with a remote server set up for deployment.

This works so far.

### Problem:

Angular 2 and other node modules are managed on the remote server by invoking `npm install ...`. The npm updates don't get recognized by PhpStorm as they are just happening remotely, not local. This leads to situations where my local `node_modules` are out of sync with remote `node_modules`.

### Question:

How can I avoid getting local and remote `node_modules` out of sync while maintaining a fast and productive dev environment?

---

My current setup is:

- git repository on bitbucket.org
- developing on my local machine (which has no webserver at all)
- deploy to remote server (where I can execute the code)
- `/node_modules` is included in git repository

What I tried so far:

- Development on remote server. Way to slow.
- Tried to include `node_modules` as an external library in PhpStorm, as I can access the remote server via samba. PhpStorm can not resolve TypeScript includes like `import {Component} from '@angular/core';`

Any hints on how to set up a project like mine would be great.

Comment: you can enable notification about changes made on remote server - see https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Sync+changes+and+automatic+upload+to+a+deployment+server+in+PhpStorm#SyncchangesandautomaticuploadtoadeploymentserverinPhpStorm-(optional)5.Notifyaboutremotechanges. Does it work for you?